# Speech to text result = null error

Tags: android, imageview, speech-to-text

Brief Description: The application will display random images to the user based off the words from the word bank file and the user will have to identify the name of the image, (single word). The user can either "pass" by clicking the pass button or identify the image and then the "next" button will pop up directing them to the next image.
At the last image, the next button will be replaced by "Continue" button which will lead the user to the game over screen

Problem: 
Every time, i reached the last picture and attempt to answer it or when the "continue" button appears, and I click it also causes the game to crash.  "unfortunately, pic has stopped"

The error message is pointing to the line:

```
     if (wordBANK.contains(result.get(0).toLowerCase()) && UnSpokenList.get(randomNum).contains(result.get(0).toLowerCase())) {
```

I don't see any problem with this line as it been working fine for the previous images until the very last image.

**Main.Java**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int VR_Request = 100;

    Button restart;
    Button mainMenu;
    Button pass;
    Button next;
    Button last2image;
    Button gameOver;

    TextView speechInput;
    TextView matchOrNot;

    String[] wordBank;
    ArrayList<String> wordBANK;

    Spinner wordList;
    Spinner SpokenWords;

    ArrayList<String> UnSpokenList;
    ArrayList<String> SpokenList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> wordList_adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> SpokenList_adapter;

    ImageButton speechBtn;

    ImageView image;
    Resources res;
    int resID;

    Random random;
    int randomNum;

    int previous;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pictionary);

        speechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.english_word1);
        matchOrNot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matchOrNot1);


        wordBank = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Words);

        speechBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mic_pic_button1);

        wordBANK = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordBank));
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        res = getResources();

        restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartButton1);
        mainMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainMenubutton1);
        pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passButton);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        last2image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.last2image);
        gameOver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameOverTime);

        wordList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wordsList1);
        SpokenWords = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spokenWords1);

        UnSpokenList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordBank));
        SpokenList = new ArrayList<String>(wordBank.length+1);

        UnSpokenList.add(0, "Word Bank:");
        SpokenList.add(0,"Spoken Words:");
        wordList_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, UnSpokenList);
        wordList_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        wordList.setAdapter(wordList_adapter);
        SpokenList_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpokenList);
        SpokenList_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        SpokenWords.setAdapter(SpokenList_adapter);

        random = new Random();
        randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()-1)+1);
        resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(randomNum), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
        image.setImageResource(resID);

        pass.setClickable(true);
        pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        next.setClickable(false);
        next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        speechBtn.setClickable(true);
        last2image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        last2image.setClickable(false);
        gameOver.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        gameOver.setClickable(false);

        restart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mainMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void onMicButton(View view) {
    }

    public void onNext(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.nextButton){
            speechInput.setText("");
            matchOrNot.setText("");

            randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()-1) + 1);

            resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(randomNum), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(resID);

            next.setClickable(false);
            next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            pass.setClickable(true);
            pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            speechBtn.setClickable(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function occurs when the user plays all the way to last 2 image left in game
     */
    public void onlastPair(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.last2image){

            speechInput.setText("");
            matchOrNot.setText("");

            resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()-1), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(resID);

            speechBtn.setClickable(true);

            next.setClickable(false);
            next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pass.setClickable(true);
            pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            last2image.setClickable(true);
            last2image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if(UnSpokenList.size() == 2){
                pass.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onGameOver(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.gameOverTime) {
            speechInput.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            speechInput.setText("GAME OVER!");
            matchOrNot.setText("");
            image.setImageBitmap(null);
            restart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mainMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            last2image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            gameOver.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void onPass(View view){

    }


    public void onResetPic(View view){

    }


    public void reset(){
        }

    public void MainMenu(View view){

    }

    public void promptSpeechInput() {

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode == VR_Request && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> result = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            if (wordBANK.contains(result.get(0).toLowerCase()) && UnSpokenList.get(randomNum).contains(result.get(0).toLowerCase())) {
                speechInput.setText(result.get(0).toUpperCase());

                matchOrNot.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                matchOrNot.setText("CORRECT!");

                UnSpokenList.remove(result.get(0).toLowerCase());
                SpokenList.add(result.get(0).toLowerCase());

                pass.setClickable(false);
                pass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                speechBtn.setClickable(false);

                if (UnSpokenList.size() > 3) {
                    next.setClickable(true);
                    next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    last2image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    last2image.setClickable(true);
                }
                if (UnSpokenList.size() == 1) {
                    last2image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    last2image.setClickable(false);
                    next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    next.setClickable(false);
                    gameOver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gameOver.setClickable(true);
                }
            }else{
                speechInput.setText(result.get(0).toLowerCase());

                matchOrNot.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                matchOrNot.setText("TRY AGAIN!");

                pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pass.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
08-17 23:46:18.397 27287-27287/com.example.speechtotext D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-17 23:46:18.397 27287-27287/com.example.speechtotext E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.speechtotext, PID: 27287
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.speechtotext.Main}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                 at com.example.speechtotext.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:343)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-17 23:46:21.356 27287-27287/com.example.speechtotext I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27287 SIG: 9
```

Any ideas? Thank You in advance!

Comment: You'd never end up at the 0th index with `randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()-1) + 1);`...is that intentional?

Comment: yes, it is intentional as the first element is "Word Bank:" which is to display the name of the spinner list. That word is not in the main word bank file and it is not an image to be displayed.
UnSpokenList.add(0, "Word Bank:"); It was intented to be from 1 - max size

Comment: For the last picture, as you don't need to use the randomNum any more, so you forgot to change it.

Comment: ohh thanks, i totally missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are removing an element from `UnSpokenList` in `onActivityResult` but not altering the value of `randomNum` prior to getting the final image.

Add the following logging above the line where the app crashes and you'll see the error:

```
            Log.i("TAG", "The array size is : " + UnSpokenList.size());
            Log.i("TAG", "Attempting to get random position: " + randomNum);
```